# PHP Fatal error: Class 'JTree' not found

Tags: php, joomla

I'm not a coder, so please let me know if I'm in the wrong place. I'm an office manager who has managed to recover our Joomla website from being hacked. However I can't get into the backend of the website and our web host is not able to help. I can log in but then a blank page appears. This is the message I got from the our web host.

20160421T120205: creativelc.com.au/administrator/index.php 
PHP Fatal error: Class 'JTree' not found in /hermes/bosnaweb15a/b931/ipg.creativelearning/administrator/modules/mod_menu/menu.php on line 18

I have tried to resolve it by restoring from a fresh installation. However, it is still loading the blank page. Thus, I suggest you please contact your application vendor on this and seek their assistance further.

Thanks

Comment: Have you read this http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=430&t=374133&sid=3f69a3cd58bc97cff4e200806d3b7245&start=30 ? See the second page of the thread also. There might be your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you reinstalled Joomla, but I recommend you to do it this way:

1. Back-up everything needed
2. Install Joomla on a subdomain/different domain/localhost or similar, as testing purpose.
3. Upload a copy of your database and connect it to the subdomain/domain/localhost.

If this solution doesn't work, then your database is affected. If you get different error messages, that may be because of the missing plug-ins, you should install them from scratch.